# Not printing correctly, but still running

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class ResponseTimeProject
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Hello " + name + ". Please answer as fast as you can." + "\n\nHit <ENTER> when ready for the question.");
    in.nextLine();

    for (int count = 0; count < 4; count ++) {

      String alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

      int character=(int)(Math.random()*26);

      String s = alphabet.substring(character, character+1);

      Random r = new Random();
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
      }

      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      System.out.print("What is the next letter in the alphabet?" + " ");
      String response = in.nextLine();

      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      String outcome;

      if (alphabet.substring(character+1, character+2).equals(response)) {
        outcome = "Correct!";
      } else {
        outcome = "Incorrect.";
      }

      long reactionTime = endTime - startTime;
      System.out.println(outcome);
      System.out.println("The average time it took you was " + reactionTime + " milliseconds"); 
      System.out.println("Thank you "  + name + ", goodbye.");

    }
  }
}
```

HELP:
This code runs but it gives me the wrong answer. I do not know what is wrong. It prints incorrect for the right outcome. Not sure what I need to fix

Comment: `System.out.println(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));`?? I think you need to start by reading the JavaDoc entries for those methods

Comment: The code is asking what the next letter is, I put in the correct next letter but it says incorrect

Comment: Maybe he is a... mad programmer.

Comment: why are you using a `substring()` to get a character from a String? However, _try debugging the program_. Print the alphabet.substring() value and the response value to see if they match.

Comment: What is up with a loop for obtaining a given character: `for (i = 0; i < i; i++) { // blah }`. What is this loop doing here at all?

Answer (score 0):

The code in question is really a total mess (substring to get a character from a String, loops of a single iteration, etc.). But the fundamental issue relating to the question is that the "next letter in the alphabet" depends upon an output that is printed but never stored. It is currently

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
}
```

and therefore never saved, so there is nothing to compare it to.

So, save the next character, and then print it.

```
char nextLetter = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length());
```

Then in the comparison, for the response, check the response against an actual value, not some random substring from the alphabet String.

```
response = in.nextLine();
char chkChar = response.charAt(0);
if (chkChar == nextLetter) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Also, just to point out, the string `alphabet` stores all the of the alphabets in uppercase. If OP wishes for case-insensitivity, he can make use of `toUpperCase()` on the user input. Otherwise, lowercase inputs will also be deemed incorrect. @MadSusz

Comment: Bravo, @KevinO, for trying to formulate a proper answer, >_<